# jQuery .each() method or .html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small application that loads HTML content from a database via PHP back end. At the moment jQuery loads the html data from the PHP file to a DIV on the main page thie happens every 5 seconds or so with a `setInterval() $('#div').html(html);`. All the formatting is done in CSS and the data structure is echoed out from the php file. I also use jQuery to post data to the database via PHP, as this is a small chat app. My question is what is the faster or more efficient way to pull this data, either to use json and parse each element into its structure via jQuery `.each()` method or continue to use my current `.html()` method to load the data and echo out the full data structure through PHP? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Define "better". Pulling JSON intead of HTML will require (a little) more work on the client side, but a (slightly) faster network download. Generally this is considered preferable, but if you're not having any problems reported, why worry about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Issuing a single call to `html()` instead of building the DOM tree incrementally will most probably be *faster*.

Comment: This isn't asking a specific question, so I suspect it will get closed, but I wanted to comment that either approach is valid, it's just a matter of philosphy.  If you have the PHP backend return JSON data, then the PHP backend will be completely separated from the front end and you could then use it for types of UI (a mobile version of the site, a smartphone app...) or other views of the same UI.

Comment: Corrected "better", but I see you understood my concept. I experience a slight problem which i figured this might help to fix, at times when i try to post a message the `DIV` in view would not be updated with the newly posted data and on the second or third run of the `setInterval()` then 2 or 3 copies of the data would be present. Somewhat like it was stopped in buffer then released, my logic was getting a more efficient pulling method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally echo the structure to a JSON object in php. then in javascript parse it and place it into its container via .html().

I think this is much better than the alternative as you have nice clean editable code in the php and just use the javascript to put it where it needs to go.

in my php:

```
    $response['error'] = false; // if you get an error set this to true
    $response['html'] = ''; // set this wherever you like.
    alternately if you needed to break it up
    $response['html_A'] = '';
    $response['html_B'] = '';


>     in the end


    echo json_encode($response);
```

in javascript

```
$.post(function(r){
  response = JSON.parse(r);
   if (response.error !== true){
     $('#someDiv').html(response.html);
   }
   else {
     alert (response.errorMessage);
   }
}
```

doing an $.each loop seems laborious. Especially when you decide to add/mod some of the output generated by the php.